# Is it possible with Highcharts Polar Chart to have curved lines connecting the points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-visualization, radar-chart

I am looking at using Highcharts as a replacement for Google Image Charts.

Polar (Radar) graphs on Google Image Charts had the option of chart type 'rs' which had curved lines connecting the points on the graph instead of straight lines.

[Google Image Charts - Radar Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/radar_charts)

Is that possible in Highcharts 7.x? I am looking through the online docs for the options and I don't see that specified anywhere, and I keep getting Spline graph info when I try to search for it.

Comment: Hi @Joseph Michael, Please check the polar: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar and the spiderweb chart: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider. These types of charts with `spline` series should match your requirements.

Comment: You can take a spline and apply it to the polar chart? When looking into the spline I thought it was its own distinct type of chart? At least the docs made that out to be https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-inverted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `polar` option is independent of the chart `type`, so you can use both options:

```
chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'spline'
},
```

Or specify the series types:

```
chart: {
    polar: true
},
series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    data: [...]
}, {
    type: 'column',
    data: [...]
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zp7vna4f/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.polar

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type